# How to set a pending Rollback on a Transaction?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, transactions, commit

I've been working with MySQL Transactions to encapsulate the several read/writes that execute throughout my method.

```
private void ReceiveOrderConfirm(object sender)
{
    Db.BeginTransaction();
    //succeeds
    Thing1();

    //canceled by user 
    Thing2();

    //succeeds
    Thing3();
    Db.CommitTransaction();
}
```

So here's my example situation, simplified for clarity's sake.

I've got a method which does several things inside of it, occassionally passing off control to other methods to execute and return. All three of these methods don`t error in this example. but the user is given the option to press a Cancel button in Thing2(). Right now if I were to just simply call a Rollback on my transaction when the user presses cancel, then Thing3 will execute and succeed, being automatically wrapped in it's own new trasnaction that autocommits.

My question is, is there a way to set a condition that will automatically fail the commit when it is attempted at the end of all three of these methods. So that they all rollback together, as opposed to simply the first half.

Answer (score 1):

You could let `Thing2` return a bool for success:

```
if (Thing2())
{
    //
    // success, continue
    //
    Thing3();
    Db.CommitTransaction();
}
else
{
    //
    // cancelled, rollback
    //
    Db.RollbackTransaction();
}
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking of as well, but I was hoping for a more overarching solution that I could append to the cancel command or use in a broader scope of scenarios. I'd have to do this in many places throughout the system.